# Visual Studio 2010 configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration

I have a Windows 32-bit project designed in Visual Studio 2010 using C++. When I build and compile it on one computer, I get the GUI and the project works. However, on a different computer it only shows me a command prompt and then exits. What configuration changes do I need to make to see the GUI on this computer?

Comment: Please be more precise: Are you saying that the build works on both machines, but your program, when it executes, doesn't? If so, in what ways could configuring VS help?

Comment: Build works on both. I will get .exe also on both ! both if I click on "start debugging" in one of them I will get GUI (the program) . in one of them I will get a command prompt window! I need to get the GUI as well in the second one.

Comment: Does the console window provide any message? Can you set a breakpoint at the start of your code and check which line of code actually opens the console window? Also, check if there are differences in OS setup, eg. 32/64bit.

Comment: It will be exited quickly but I know that it needs to have some parameters to work ! Actually the written program supports both Command prompt option and GUI ! I want it to only show me the GUI! It should have an option on VS. the problem is not with the program

Comment: Do both machines have the same .NET Framework version(s) installed? Are we talking about a Windows Forms application? Do you have the Application Framework Enabled (project properties)?

Comment: The answer for all your 3 questions is Yes